# How does deriving work in protobuf-net?

Tags: protobuf-net, derived-types

Like I would do in C#:

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass {}
```

is there a way to recreate this behaviour with messages in a proto-file?
So that the `DerivedClass` is of type `BaseClass` and can inherit its properties.

I tried to `extend` my base message, but this yields a different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that this is:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(7, typeof(DerivedClass))]
public class BaseClass {}

[ProtoContract]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {}
```

Then we can use:

```
string proto = Serializer.GetProto<BaseClass>();
```

to see how protobuf-net is interpreting it:

```
message BaseClass {
   // the following represent sub-types; at most 1 should have a value
   optional DerivedClass DerivedClass = 7;
}
message DerivedClass {
}
```

This would actually map fairly well to the new `oneof` - simply, `GetProto` hasn't been updated to use the new syntax (it wouldn't impact the output, though). But the following would also be equivalent:

```
message BaseClass {
    oneof subtypes {
        // the following represent sub-types; at most 1 should have a value
        DerivedClass DerivedClass = 7;
        AnotherDerivedClass AnotherDerivedClass = 8;
        AndOneMoreForLuck AndOneMoreForLuck = 9;
    }
}
message DerivedClass {
}
message AnotherDerivedClass {
}
message AndOneMoreForLuck {
}
```